# Consuming json with Angular 5 and Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, json, angular

I have this Api I dont know how to consume or to access to the data array
I try this but i dont get the product list in P 
I got this  API

```
{"data":[{"name":"product1","price":55,"created_at":"2017-11-29 00:00:00","updated_at":"2017-11-29 00:00:00"},{"name":"product2","price":250,"created_at":"2017-12-09 00:00:00","updated_at":"2017-12-09 00:00:00"}]}
```

My Angular Code

```
p:Product[];
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products';
  }

  getProducts() {
     this.http.get(this.url, {headers: this.prepareHeaders()}).map(res=>res.json())
     .subscribe( p => this.p = p);
     console.log(this.p.toString());
     }
```

Comment: http requests are asynchronous. you cannot perform `this.p.toString()` before the asynchronous call finishes. Any actions you want to perform on `this.p` must happen after you receive the data. So you can do something like `.subscribe(p => {this.p = p; console.log(this.p.toString());});`

Answer (score 0):

```
getProducts() {
 this.http.get(this.url, {headers: 
 this.prepareHeaders()}).map(res=>res.json())
 .subscribe( p => {this.p = p; console.log(p);});
 }
```

Here is a nice example of Http.get with Observable & promise [Example](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-http-get-example)